# I have to change the input type to tel from text of the html form on runtime using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery.
I have HTML form and I want to change the input type from text to tel when user clicks the input box using jquery. Also there would be many field having input type as text(creating aem component) and even the class is name would be same hence, selection of that form element should be pattern="[+0-9()-]*".

```
<form class="form">
    <input type="text" name="myPassword" pattern="[+0-9()-]*"/>
    <input type="text" name="myPassword" />
</form>
```

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('.form').find(pattern:'[+0-9()-]*').each(function() {
       $("<input type='tel' />").attr({ name: this.name, value: this.value }).insertBefore(this);
    }).remove();
});
```

The output should be when user just click the input field the input type should be change to "tel".

Comment: Have you searched your question first? You know what you want to do, that's good. Just add "how to" before that and enter it into Google. There will be a bunch of results. And I don't think jQuery has this syntax `.find(pattern:'[+0-9()-]*')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the find() part. Here is the right syntax:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(".form").find("input[pattern='[+0-9()-\]*']").each(function() {
       $("<input type='tel' />").attr({ name: this.name, value: this.value }).insertBefore(this);
    }).remove();
});
```

Now about what you said in your comment, i think it can be done in a much simpler way. Replace the hole thing with a click listener on inputs with the pattern `[+0-9()-\]*`, and change their type to `tel` when they are clicked:

```
$("input[pattern='[+0-9()-\]*']").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("type", "tel");
});
```

Also, I don't know if you really need to wait for the inputs to be clicked, but if not, you could simply change their types at page load by running this when document is ready:

```
$("input[pattern='[+0-9()-\]*']").attr("type", "tel");
```

Comment: But is it possible like instead of button when user just click the input filed the input type changes to tel.

Comment: Also, when I click the button the pattern is removed I don't want to remove the pattern for the input field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it is not working.

Comment: Please refer the link: https://codepen.io/restar312/pen/mddRRJW

Comment: Thanks @François Huppé

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about my comprehension of your problem but here's a hint on how to do it

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('.form').find('[name="myPassword"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('type', 'tel');
  });
});
```